# Python: Paramiko: display result of cat command

Tags: python, unix, paramiko

I have been struggling with getting output from cat command

```
 stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command("'cat /finusers3/bway/download/input2.dat|wc -l'", False)
        for line in iter(stdout.readline, ""):
           print(line)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I think subprocess is what you need:

```
from subprocess import Popen
from subprocess import PIPE

cmd = 'ls -la'.split()
popen_cmd = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE)
output = popen_cmd.communicate()[0]
```

Comment: i am trying this using Paramiko. I have no idea how subprocess will fit in this code.